# Firebase Notification is not sent when minifyEnabled=true

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, proguard, firebase-notifications

I've been having a problem for days. I'm sending notifications to my Android app with Firebase Cloud Messaging. When minifyEnabled=false, notifications come in release mode. However, when minifyEnabled=true, notifications do not come. Whatever I added to the proguard-rules.pro file still did not come. Any ideas?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.umit.app">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.zxing.client.android" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".umitapp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"          
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <service
            android:name=".application.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        
        ...
        ..
        .
```

**FirebaseMessagingService**

```
class FirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    
    override fun onNewToken(newToken: String) {
        super.onNewToken(newToken)
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
        App.sendNotification(remoteMessage)
    }       
}
```

**proguardrules.pro**

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.google.crypto.** { *; }
-keep class * extends com.google.crypto.tink.shaded.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite { *; }
-keep class com.google.googlesignin.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.google.googlesignin.* { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.auth.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.**{ *; }
-keep class androidx.renderscript.** { *; }
-keep class com.fivehundredpx.android.blur.BlurringView.** { *; }
-keepnames class androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-allowaccessmodification
-repackageclasses ''
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.shaded.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
-keepnames class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.shaded.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.**
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$* { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-keep class com.transistorsoft.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.transistorsoft.**
-keep class ch.qos.** { *; }
-keep class org.slf4j.** { *; }
-dontwarn ch.qos.logback.core.net.*
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class io.invertase.firebase.** { *; }
-dontwarn io.invertase.firebase.**
-keep class com.rt2zz.reactnativecontacts.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers class com.rt2zz.reactnativecontacts.** {*;}
-ignorewarnings
-keep class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$* { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat { *; }
-keep class com.pusher.pushnotifications.** {
  *;
}
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
-keep, allowobfuscation public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep, allowobfuscation public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep, allowobfuscation public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep, allowobfuscation public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep, allowobfuscation public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep, allowobfuscation public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep, allowobfuscation public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep, allowobfuscation public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
-dontwarn java.util.concurrent.Flow*
-keep class com.netmera.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
public *;
}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep,allowshrinking class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
 -keep class com.microsoft.signalr.** { *; }
 -keep interface com.microsoft.signalr.** { *; }
 -keep public class androidx.preference.Preference {
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 }
 -keep public class * extends androidx.preference.Preference {
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 }
-keepnames class * extends android.os.Parcelable
-keepnames class * extends java.io.Serializable

-keep public class android.app.NotificationChannel.** { *; }
-keep public class android.app.NotificationManager.** { *; }
-keep public class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.** { *; }
-keep public class androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage { *; }
-keep class com.umit.app.FirebaseMessagingService { *; }
```

Comment: Please do not edit questions after you received answers, at least not in a way which either invalidates answers or (as in this case) remove information which was needed to find the answers as given. You put the answerers at risk of receiving downvotes for "implausible" or "wildly guessing" answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting android sdk to android - 12 we need to set pending intent with Flag mutable / or immutable and also we need to update firebase SDK.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at this. : https://github.com/nisaefendioglu/Firebase-Cloud-Messaging